# nestjs replace service at runtime for a plugin system

Tags: nestjs

Plugin system for a nestjs app.

I have some kind of service that lives on "core" module.
This module is supposed to be a black box, completely sealed.
The only way to add new feature is to inject new modules on the system and, eventually,
replace some services of the core module.

The problem:
Ho do i replace a service at runtime? (@Injectable)

The idea is to replace the old class with a new one with enhanced feature.

Comment: Why would you change your service at runtime?

Comment: For implementing plugins, adding custom logic to a black box, in a functional style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Module({
providers: [{provide: OldServiceClass, useClass: NewServiceClass}]
})
export class FeatureModule {}
```

Comment: I'm actually doing something similar to this, using a Dynamic Module to allow for a class to be passed in, then using a factory and custom provider to determine which variant of the class to use, the default one, or the custom one provided by the user.

Comment: Yes, i already tried this, but, it does not work, i mean, the old modules (the core hidden one) still use the old class.

Comment: if you declare the provider this way in a global module this will fix the problem